# Need help in this code Integer value return to default after setting it to something else

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem I can't figure out
the following code has four integers one of them is the "level" and after I change that value somewhere in the code and try to retrieve it later I get the default value so is there any thing wrong in this code or do I miss something

```
public class Battery_Info extends Activity {
    int scale = -1;
    int level = -1;
    int voltage = -1;
    int temp = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery__info);
    this.setTitle("Battery Information");
    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    final NotificationManager ntifymgr=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    BroadcastReceiver receive=new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scale=intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE,-1);
            level=intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            voltage=intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
            temp=intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
            TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            t.setText(""+scale);
            t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            t.setText(""+level, BufferType.EDITABLE);
            t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            t.setText(""+voltage);
            t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            t.setText(""+temp);
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receive, filter);
    final int Notif_ID=56734;
    Notification note= new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Battery Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.flags=Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    PendingIntent intent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,Battery_Info.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "BatPer", "Battery Level: "+level+"%", intent);
    ntifymgr.notify(Notif_ID, note);
}
```

when I change the value of level it changes and the textview shows that but when I use it in the notification it gives me the default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build String for notification in onCreate where level has default value ("Battery Level: "+level+"%"). Later you change level. But notification string have been already built with default value.

When level got changed you should create new notification message with current level value and update your notification with new text.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to android so I don't quite understand this why this happens if I built the notification string after changing the value of level?

Comment: code in your BroadcastReceiver will be executed after onCreate method is finished. So you create string with default level value and do not update this string after level value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this can solve your issue as I'm not expert in notification management, but if you're using the Battery_Info object to store info that are unique in the system, I would set the four members as static.

Doing so, even if you create new Battery_Info objects (for any reason), the members keep the last value and are not reset to their default value.

Comment: I thought so myself as I am not an expert in android at all but it didn't work, thank you for your try, but do you think logically that there is anything wrong with this code?

Comment: I think you should follow Leonidos advice: the notification is created with the default value. If I had designed the app, I would have put the notification creation inside the OnReceive method, but it strongly depend on the desired behaviour (e.g., do you want a new notification every time the battery level changes?)

Comment: thank you I got it now I do followed his advice and it worked fine with me thank you again